# How to make system( ... ) return a stream of strings as output after running Ruby script?

Tags: ruby

I am writing a ruby script where I am making use of the command

```
system('git log')
```

along with some flags and formatting preferences to show me the time, revision id and file name of each file that was added in a repo.

How can I make the result of this command (i.e which is the information stated above for each file) to be a single string, one for each file added in repo and then put all these strings inside an array?

Example of current result:

```
2016-10-11T22:07:06+01:00 b3d0893: example.txt
2016-10-11T22:06:06+01:00 b3d0893: example1.txt
```

I want the above to be two different strings and then put them in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Kernel#system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005971) just returns `true` or `false` depending on the success of the call. STDOUT from the call is simply output, so you can't really do anything with it, as you've found out.

If you switch to using [backticks](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005960) instead you should get a `String` returned with STDOUT from the command:

```
output = `git log`
```

To split that output string into an `Array` of lines, use `String#split`, so you get something like

```
output = `git log`
lines = output.split(/\n/)
```

Comment: Thank you, one more question before ticking your answer as the ideal one.  How can I have output in the screen without getting a double line in between the contents?

Comment: I am getting double lines when I use puts!

Comment: Feel free to open a new question if you have questions about how to output the contents of an `Array` using `puts`. Make sure to include the code you're using and preferably a sample array to reproduce the problem with.